# Strange compilation error after installing freeglut

Tags: installation, dev-c++, freeglut

I followed [this installation video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Qkpaewj-7Y) to install Dev C++ and freeglut for a class, and I did so precisely according to the instructions, but I'm getting a strange compilation error when I toss in some prewritten test code to try and figure it out.

[image: Error]

The teacher speculates that it might have something to do with not having `freeglut.h` but as this picture shows, it is indeed there. I need to have this working for class, if anyone can give me any advice that would be awesome.

[image: Correct?]

UPDATE: I tried changing the header file at the suggested point, but that didn't help much... I checked the source header file and it looked like the below picture in Notepad. Perhaps it has to do with Dev C++?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try opening the project in a blank application! That video asks you to open a console application which doesn't make sense for graphical code.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the header file got mangled.  Your picture shows this:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
#endif
    extern "C" {
```

but that doesn't make sense.  It should be this:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
    extern "C" {
#endif
```

Comment: I gave that suggestion a shot and updated my post accordingly. What could this be?

Comment: could be something in main.cpp